# How to Get only first 10 record from method http Get in service Api Angular

Tags: angular, api, http, get

I have this method to get Products List
this method return all records , but i need to return only 10 first record from the service not the ts component :

```
  getProduits():Observable<any[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl+'/Fproduits'); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1.** Implement additional logic on the backend side. For example, you can send a request with a query string to specify the required limit of items:

```js
getProduits():Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.APIUrl}/Fproduits?limit=10`); 
}
```

**Option 2.** Transform your response using pipe:

```js
getProduits():Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.APIUrl}/Fproduits`).pipe(map((el) => el.slice(0, 3))); 
}
```

**This is my example:**

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const limit = 3;

const get = () => of(array); // returns an observable

const getProduts = limit => (
    get()
        .pipe(map(response => response.slice(0, limit)))
        .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
)

getProduts(limit);
```

Comment: Thnks , but not working

Comment: @AspCoreStudent Please take a look on my example

Comment: Now , Option 2 work but too slow to retrieve result , How can i return the 10 records fastly

Comment: I would recommend implementing logic on the backend side (option 1)