# Filter Database result From Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a result variable in angular component .ts file which holds the data returned from database .  Now i have to filter the result variable to show only 20 records and date in ascending or descending order .
I am very new to angular dont know too much how to filter this .
Can you please give idea how this can he done .

```
let result;
            switch (hoursType) {
                case HoursType.workhours:
                    result = await this.service.getWorHours(this.username.value);
                    break;
                case HoursType.Outofhourwork:
                    result = await this.service.getNonWork(this.username.value);
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Maybe this can help to get 20 records while making an api call:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70000484/how-to-get-only-first-10-record-from-method-http-get-in-service-api-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//to get 20 records
var myItems = result.slice(0, 20);

//to sort by date
 myItems.sort((a, b) => {
      return <any>new Date(b.date) - <any>new Date(a.date);
    });
```